# Graphing/Plotting multivariate profit function with inequalities

Tags: plotting, functions

I have the following profit function which I would like to 3Dplot in Mathemathica:

```
Profit = (8c^2-16c*s-10c-4s-3)/(32s+16)
```

, where `c` denotes marginal cost.

with the defined ranges:

0 <= c <= 1/2 and 0 < s < (3+2c)/4

c > 1/2 and (-1+2c)/4 < s < (3+2c)/4

Currently, I only know how to 3Dplot a function with real numbers. Fx:

```
Plot3D[8 c^2 - 16 c s - 10 c - 4 s - (3 s)/32 + 16, {c, 0, 2}, {s, 0, 
  1}]
```

I get an error if I do something like this:

```
Plot3D[((8 c^2 - 16* c* s - 10 c - 4 s - 3)/(32 s + 16)), {c, 
    0, (1/2)}, {s, 0, ((3 + 2 c)/4)}, {c, (1/2), 
    inf}, {s, ((-1 + 2 c)/4)}, ((3 + 2 c)/4)} ]
```

Comment: Does this do it? `Plot3D[profit, {c, 0, 2}, {s, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[Or[
    0 <= #1 <= 1/2 && 
     0 <= #2 <= (3 + 2 #1)/4, #1 > 1/
      2 && (-1 + 2 #1) < #2 < (3 + 2 #1)/4]]]`

Comment: @march just tried. The output is an empty box.

Comment: Probably because I used `profit` instead of `Profit`. Capitalization matters. Also, you should add `PlotRange -> All` to the list of options.

Comment: Corrected profit to Profit and added `PlotRange -> All` at the end: `Plot3D[Profit, {c, 0, 2}, {s, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[Or[
    0 <= #1 <= 1/2 && 
     0 <= #2 <= (3 + 2 #1)/4, #1 > 
      1/2 && (-1 + 2 #1) < #2 < (3 + 2 #1)/4]], PlotRange -> All]` I still get an empty box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed snippets are working on `10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Profit = (8 c^2 - 16 c*s - 10 c - 4 s - 3)/(32 s + 16)
```

> $\frac{8 c^2-16 c s-10 c-4 s-3}{32 s+16}$

```
Plot3D[Profit, {c, -0.286031, 0.286031}, {s, -0.347656, 0.347656}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[8 c^2 - 16 c s - 10 c - 4 s - (3 s)/32 + 16, {c, 0, 2}, {s,  0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Profit, {c, 0, 2}, {s, 0, 1}, 
RegionFunction -> 
Function[Or[
 0 <= #1 <= 1/2 && 
  0 <= #2 <= (3 + 2 #1)/4, #1 > 
   1/2 && (-1 + 2 #1) < #2 < (3 + 2 #1)/4]]]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Profit, {c, 0, 2}, {s, 0, 1}, 
RegionFunction -> 
Function[Or[
 0 <= #1 <= 1/2 && 
  0 <= #2 <= (3 + 2 #1)/4, #1 > 
   1/2 && (-1 + 2 #1) < #2 < (3 + 2 #1)/4]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]